# VMware customization specification for Linux CentOS server not prompting for gateway

Tags: vmware-esxi, linux-networking, centos7, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

So I created a customization specification in VMware 6.0.0 and configured it so that it prompts the user whan a vm is deployed from my CentOS 7 template.

[image]

The ip address, subnet mask and hostname are prompted, but not the gateway resulting in a server with no network connectivity. Ok I could configure /etc/sysconfig/network with a fixed gateway, but this would mean this template only works for one ip range. How should I solve this issue? I don't see any way to prompt for the gateway when a vm is deployed from the template.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to do the above. The gui is a bit confusing, as showing radio buttons makes you think you can only choose one option, but in fact what I needed was a combination of prompt and specified ip settings for the gateway only. Then I just needed to make a separate customization specification for each vlan... Not very logical if you ask me, but it works..

[image]